# How do I get characters that are non-letters and non-digits appended in a list?

Tags: python, counting, cpu-word, identify

This is about plain word counting, to collect which words appear in a document and how how often.

I try to write a function were the input is a list of text lines. I go through all lines, split them into words, accumulate the recognized words and finally return the complete list.

First I have a while-loop that goes through all the characters in the list, and but ignores the white spaces. Inside this while loop I also try to recognize what kind of words I have. In this context, there are three kinds of words:

- those starting with a letter;
- those starting with a digit;
- and those which contain only one character which is neither letter nor digit.

I have three if statements which check what kind of character I have. When I know what kind of word I have encountered, I try to extract the word itself. When the word starts with a letter or a digit, I take all consecutive characters of the same kind as part of the word.

But, in the third if statement, when I take care of the case when the current character is neither a letter nor a digit, I get problems.

When I give the input

```
wordfreq.tokenize(['15,    delicious&   Tarts.'])
```

I want the output to be

```
['15', ',', 'delicious', '&', 'tarts', '.']
```

When I test the function in the Python Console, it looks like this:

```
PyDev console: starting.
Python 3.7.4 (v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 14:54:52) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
import wordfreq
wordfreq.tokenize(['15,    delicious&   Tarts.'])
['15', 'delicious', 'tarts']
```

The function does not take neither the comma, the ampersand nor the dot into account! How do I fix this?
See below for the code.

(The lower() method is because I want to ignore capitalization, e.g. 'Tarts' and 'tarts' are really the same words.)

```
# wordfreq.py

def tokenize(lines):
    words = []
    for line in lines:
        start = 0
        while start < len(line):
            while line[start].isspace():
                start = start + 1
            if line[start].isalpha():
                end = start
                while line[end].isalpha():
                    end = end + 1
                word = line[start:end]
                words.append(word.lower())
                start = end
            elif line[start].isdigit():
                end = start
                while line[end].isdigit():
                    end = end + 1
                word = line[start:end]
                words.append(word)
                start = end
            else:
                words.append(line[start])
            start = start + 1
    return words
```

Comment: Please add an example of how a typical input to your function looks like what the desired output would be

Comment: See example above of desired input/output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're doing upper and lower but here's how you can split it:

```
input = ['15,    delicious&   Tarts.']
line = input[0]
words = line.split(' ')
words = [word for word in words if word]
out:
['15,', 'delicious&', 'Tarts.']
```

edit, saw that you edited how you want your output to be. Just skip this line to get that output:

```
    words = [word for word in words if word]
```

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.groupby` could simplify this quite a bit. Basically, you group the characters in your string based on the category or type of character - alpha, digit or punctuation. In this example I only defined those three categories, but you can define as many or as little categories as you wish. Any character that doesn't match any of the categories (whitespace, in this example) is ignored:

```
def get_tokens(string):
    from itertools import groupby
    from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits, punctuation as punct
    alpha = ascii_lowercase + ascii_uppercase

    yield from ("".join(group) for key, group in groupby(string, key=lambda char: next((category for category in (alpha, digits, punct) if char in category), "")) if key)

print(list(get_tokens("15,    delicious&   Tarts.")))
```

Output:

```
['15', ',', 'delicious', '&', 'Tarts', '.']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was. The line

```
start = start + 1
```

where supposed to be in the last else statement.

So my code looks like this and gives me the desired input specified above:

```
def tokenize(lines):
    words = []
    for line in lines:
        start = 0
        while start < len(line):
            while line[start].isspace():
                start = start + 1
            end = start
            if line[start].isalpha():
                while line[end].isalpha():
                    end = end + 1
                word = line[start:end]
                word = word.lower()
                words.append(word)
                start = end
            elif line[start].isdigit():
                while line[end].isdigit():
                    end = end + 1
                word = line[start:end]
                words.append(word)
                start = end
            else:
                word = line[start]
                words.append(word)
                start = start + 1
    return words
```

However, when I use the testing script below to make sure that there is no corner cases that the function 'tokenize' missed out;...

```
import io
import sys
import importlib.util

def test(fun,x,y):
    global pass_tests, fail_tests
    if type(x) == tuple:
        z = fun(*x)
    else:
        z = fun(x)
    if y == z:
        pass_tests = pass_tests + 1
    else:
        if type(x) == tuple:
            s = repr(x)
        else:
            s = "("+repr(x)+")"
        print("Condition failed:")
        print("   "+fun.__name__+s+" == "+repr(y))
        print(fun.__name__+" returned/printed:")
        print(str(z))
        fail_tests = fail_tests + 1

def run(src_path=None):
    global pass_tests, fail_tests

    if src_path == None:
        import wordfreq
    else:
        spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("wordfreq", src_path+"/wordfreq.py")
        wordfreq = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(wordfreq)

    pass_tests = 0
    fail_tests = 0
    fun_count  = 0

    def printTopMost(freq,n):
        saved = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = io.StringIO()
        wordfreq.printTopMost(freq,n)
        out = sys.stdout.getvalue()
        sys.stdout = saved
        return out

    if hasattr(wordfreq, "tokenize"):
        fun_count = fun_count + 1
        test(wordfreq.tokenize, [], [])
        test(wordfreq.tokenize, [""], [])
        test(wordfreq.tokenize, ["   "], [])
        test(wordfreq.tokenize, ["This is a simple sentence"], ["this","is","a","simple","sentence"])
        test(wordfreq.tokenize, ["I told you!"], ["i","told","you","!"])
        test(wordfreq.tokenize, ["The 10 little chicks"], ["the","10","little","chicks"])
        test(wordfreq.tokenize, ["15th anniversary"], ["15","th","anniversary"])
        test(wordfreq.tokenize, ["He is in the room, she said."], ["he","is","in","the","room",",","she","said","."])
    else:
        print("tokenize is not implemented yet!")

    if hasattr(wordfreq, "countWords"):
        fun_count = fun_count + 1
        test(wordfreq.countWords, ([],[]), {})
        test(wordfreq.countWords, (["clean","water"],[]), {"clean":1,"water":1})
        test(wordfreq.countWords, (["clean","water","is","drinkable","water"],[]), {"clean":1,"water":2,"is":1,"drinkable":1})
        test(wordfreq.countWords, (["clean","water","is","drinkable","water"],["is"]), {"clean":1,"water":2,"drinkable":1})
    else:
        print("countWords is not implemented yet!")

    if hasattr(wordfreq, "printTopMost"):
        fun_count = fun_count + 1
        test(printTopMost,({},10),"")
        test(printTopMost,({"horror": 5, "happiness": 15},0),"")
        test(printTopMost,({"C": 3, "python": 5, "haskell": 2, "java": 1},3),"python                  5\nC                       3\nhaskell                 2\n")
    else:
        print("printTopMost is not implemented yet!")

    print(str(pass_tests)+" out of "+str(pass_tests+fail_tests)+" passed.")

    return (fun_count == 3 and fail_tests == 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

... I get the following output:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 "/Users/ericjohannesson/Documents/Fristående kurser/DAT455 – Introduktion till programmering med Python/lab1/Laborations/Laboration_1/test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ericjohannesson/Documents/Fristående kurser/DAT455 – Introduktion till programmering med Python/lab1/Laborations/Laboration_1/test.py", line 81, in <module>
    run()
  File "/Users/ericjohannesson/Documents/Fristående kurser/DAT455 – Introduktion till programmering med Python/lab1/Laborations/Laboration_1/test.py", line 50, in run
    test(wordfreq.tokenize, ["   "], [])
  File "/Users/ericjohannesson/Documents/Fristående kurser/DAT455 – Introduktion till programmering med Python/lab1/Laborations/Laboration_1/test.py", line 10, in test
    z = fun(x)
  File "/Users/ericjohannesson/Documents/Fristående kurser/DAT455 – Introduktion till programmering med Python/lab1/Laborations/Laboration_1/wordfreq.py", line 44, in tokenize
    while line[start].isspace():
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Why does it say that the string index is out of range? How do I fix that problem?